# How to add @Expose to an id model without rewriting the original id?

Tags: playframework

Using GSon, I'd like to show the id of my model when transforming it to JSON.
But I don't want all my model to have the id exposed.

Do I have to rewrite the id line of the class Model from PlayFramework in my current Model, something like :

```
class Account extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Expose
    public Long id;

    @Expose
    public String email;

    public String password;
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`GenericModel`.](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa#genericmodel) `Model` has a generated ID, `GenericModel` hasn't. Meaning you can extends `GenericModel` to create whatever ID you want and expose it if you want.